# Factors effecting the force on a current-carrying conductor

Tags: electromagnetism

Does anyone know why it is that a stronger external magnetic field will result in a greater force on a current-carrying conductor exposed to this field? I'm struggling to find an answer to this that actually explains the physics behind it, rather than just relating it back to the formula F=BIlsintheta.

Answer (score 0):

In a sense, this cannot be *explained*.  It is just an observation of how nature works.  We can *describe* it, but not *explain* it.

One can come upon this phenomenon as a consequence of other principles, for example, the Biot-Savart law, or from Maxwell's equations.  But none of these are explanations.  You can swim upstream looking for precursor principles to the phenomenon, but you will swim for a long time and never find a starting point.  At some point you stop swimming and decide that you have reached a principle that you will simply have to accept without explanation.

Maybe someday we will know why things are the way they are.  But I doubt it.